# setting defaultValue to p-multiselect

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, primeng

my code looks like below

```
export class LkBoardStatus {
    id : number = 0;
    descr : string = '';
}
```

component.ts

```
//...
lkBoardStatusList: LkBoardStatus[] = []; 
selectedStatus: LkBoardStatus = new LkBoardStatus;

ngOnInit():void {  
        this.loadBoardStatusList();
        ../
        
        }
    
    
loadBoardStatusList(){
            this.boardService.loadBoardStatus().subscribe( posts =>{
                this.data = posts; 
                console.log('loadBoardStatusList',this.data);
                },
                error => { 
                console.log('loadBoardStatusList - error',error);
                this._errorService.handleError(error); 
                }, 
                () => {   
                this.lkBoardStatusList = this.data.boardStatusLi;
                for(let i=0; i<this.lkBoardStatusList.length; i++){
                     if(this.lkBoardStatusList[i].id == 70){
                         this.selectedStatus = this.lkBoardStatusList[i];
                     }
                 }
                 console.log(this.selectedStatus);
            }); 
                
        }
```

Here I have `selectedStatus` which is assigned a value of '70' as in for loop.
My comopnent.html is below

```
 <th *ngSwitchCase="'statusObj'" [colSpan] = "2" style="text-align:center">
    <p-multiSelect [options]="lkBoardStatusList" optionLabel="descr" [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus" defaultLabel="Select" (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')"></p-multiSelect>
```

The inspect element gives me the correct object for `selectedStatus` but onLoad the value is not getting defaulted to 70. Where am I going wrong? Suggestions please.TIA

Answer (score 1):

`selectedStatus` must be an array.

Try to replace

```
for(let i=0; i<this.lkBoardStatusList.length; i++){
    if(this.lkBoardStatusList[i].id == 70){
        this.selectedStatus = this.lkBoardStatusList[i];
    }
}
```

with

```
this.selectedStatus = this.lkBoardStatusList.filter(item => item.id == 70);
```

Comment: thank you . The above helps me to default the multiSelect to value '70' but the list has no effect. The list is still list of all vaues from 10,20...100. How would I trigger the list to default to '70' on the fly not depending on DB return value. My Db return will always be a list of all values (10,20...100). I should changemy script to default to '70' and the list in the table should also default to 70